# Is there a way to hash/encode URLs parameters using Python and Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been googling this but think I am missing the correct terminology.  Is there a way using Flask and Python to hash URL parameters?

For example, let's say I have a URL like
`https://www.myhost.com/company/1/2` where the `/1` and `/2` are parameters to pull database parameters.  However, I don't want to have them exposed to the public.

Is there a way to hash or encode these?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Sounds like you're after [encrypting/cryptography](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography_with_python/cryptography_with_python_quick_guide.htm) as hashing would render them unusable for your backend. This would come at a significant overhead though, and I'd recommend rethinking if your URL parameters are that sensitive to warrant encryption.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  Being new at this, if I am asking for a database field id in my URL, would that be a security risk?  I suppose as long as I was error-catching that the logged in user matched the id it would be ok?

Comment: If your primary index is really sensitive, maybe create a secondary index that differs from the primary key (but this is probably overreacted). And be careful to correctly configure your database (network + security) and that nobody outside could access it. And maybe you could do some shortener URL, if you want to obfuscate a little bit, this is not a security measure.